# How to change Python variables based on JSON response?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get a Python variable based on a JSON response.

When I request the JSON I want to save some of the information as

```
X = content[0]['OrderItemList'][0]['ItemID']
```

What I need is the variable `X` to change if it is a certain number.

For example, if `x = 3`, I need it be changed to `x = 5`. So far I have been able to change the variable with math and other string or integer changes. I think a loop would work but I am not sure.

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    x = content[0]['OrderItemList'][0]['ItemID'] 

    pseudocode

    if x = 2 chnage to x = 5
```

Comment: `if x == 2: x = 5`?

Comment: You are free to change the value of `x` to whatever you want... What exactly seems to be the problem?

Comment: @ Tomerikoo the problem is I want the variable change based on the json response, I don't want to change it manually.

Comment: Well you will have to write a code to do that, if by that you mean manually... I'm not sure I understand how you expect the program to change the value. Try to be more clear and add details and examples

Comment: @  jonrsharpe thank you I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set x to the value from json, then use `if/elif` statements to reassign x.

```
x = content[0]['OrderItemList'][0]['ItemID']
if x in [2, 3]:
  # if x is 2 or 3, set to 5
  x = 5
elif x == 4:
  x = 2
```

or if you have a lot of conditions on which to change x, consider using a dict :

```
changetos = {2: 5,
             3: 5,
             #... 
            }
x = content[0]['OrderItemList'][0]['ItemID']
x = changetos.get(x, x) # if x not in changetos, leave x as is
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for providing a clear and concise answer.